# How to export data from CAT to R when datasets have not been coded completely?

Tags: xml, r, supervised-learning

I've used Solomon Messing's tutorial (see link below) on how to export data from CAT to R with great success. However, when only 3/4 coders have completed coding the dataset I run into problems. Even if I delete those documents that have not been coded by all coders it seems that R is unable to parse the XML file. My guess is that the XML file from CAT is set up for the initial number of documents and coders, so that when documents and coders are removed the R script is no longer compatible. Is there a way to modify the XML file or even remove coding by certain coders? The console output looks like this: 
(I have no problems with odd characters when coding is complete by all coders.)

> doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, asText=T)

xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

Error: 1: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

2: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

3: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

4: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

5: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

6: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

http://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/cat-r-for-content-analysislabels-for-text-mining/

Comment: If this solved your problem please check and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect R is choking on the text you copied from Wordpress.  When I copied the text from that blog, there was an invisible bad character between the 0 and the ; in the lines:

grep("&#x0;", doc)

and

doc <- gsub("&#x0;", "", doc)

Make sure there's not a bad character in there, then re-run the script.  When I grep for "&#x0​;" (after removing the invisible extra character) I find one of those guys on line 22443 in your xml doc.  After removing it, I don't get those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Solomon! This solved my problem. However, R had some trouble finding "paragraphCodes", so I rearranged and modified the initial script slightly, like this:

paragraphTag <- unlist(xpathApply(doc, "//paragraph", xmlGetAttr, "paragraphTag" ))

paragraphIds <- unlist(xpathApply(doc, "//paragraph", xmlGetAttr, "paragraphId" ))

pgnum <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(paragraphTag, ".txt_"), function(x) x[[2]] )))

alldat$pgnum <- pgnum[match(para, paragraphIds)]

alldat$paragraphTag <- paragraphTag[match(para, paragraphIds)]

and now it works flawlessly!